# $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}\cdot3^{n-i} = 3^n - 2^n$ combinatorical proof

Tags: combinatorics

As stated in the title, I need to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}\cdot 3^{n-i} = 3^n - 2^n$ combinatorically.

So far I have come up with this idea:

$3^n$ might represent a trinary word with a length of $n$

$2^n$ might represent a binary word with a length of $n$

$3^n - 2^n $ hence represent all the trinary words with a length of $n$ which must contain all 3 alphabets.

Assuming everything I said is true , I can't think of a way that the left side of the equation could represent a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count the number of words from $\{a,b,c\}$ that contains at least one $c$. This is all words ($3^n$ of them) minus the words that only consist of $\{a,b\}$, of which there are $2^n$.

For the sum, split on the first position of a $c$, which is $i$ which can be $1$ to $n$.
So the first $i-1$ positions can be $a$ or $b$, and the last $n-i$ ones (position $i$ has a $c$) can be any of the three, hence the sum.

Answer (score 4):

> $3^n - 2^n $ hence represent all the trinary words with a length of $n$ which must contain all 3 alphabets.

No. It is the number of trinary words, minus the number of words that only contain the first two symbols. So it represents all trinary words which must contain at lest one copy of the third symbol.

Which hints at what the left-hand side could represent: Consider the position of the first copy of the third letter.

Comment: Arthur.Nice answer.